# AMCL and other sensor data

Tags: localization, navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested in using AMCL with other sensor data if possible. Does anybody know what kind of other sensor data can be used with AMCL for self-localization other than LIDAR and odometer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262335/amcl-and-other-sensor-data/) by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a camera that provides depth info, like the MS Kinect. Lots of info on this if you do a search on the tutorials

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-05-23**:
Thanks for your answer. How about other sensors such as IMU or GPS? Can we directly input these sensor data to AMCL? or Do we need to do some kind of transformation?

**Comment by [Navaneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/38361/navaneeth/) on 2019-06-29**:
for imu and gps you have to fuse those two to form the odom then you can give that odom to amcl